# How to center a text above an image when pressed?

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, imagebutton

I'm trying to write an application using Android Studio and I'd like to have buttons with custom background that change when pressed. My actual code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_game_button_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/new_game_button" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_game_button" />
</selector>
```

Now, I want to have a text on that Image that changes its position inside the image to always fit in the center when pressed.

Button normal:

[image]

Button pressed:

[image]

How do I do this?

Since now I've been using ImageButtons but it doesn't come in handy because I had to make two files for each button (normal and pressed), hard code the text in it and then make two other files for each language I wanted.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: Consider using visibility https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility.html

Comment: Use a 9patch drawable as background. What you're trying to achieve is a pretty standard button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this creating another class that inherits from the Button one:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.mycompany.myapp.R;

public class BlueOffsetButton extends Button {

    public BlueOffsetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public BlueOffsetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BlueOffsetButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean value = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        //If not clickable
        if(!this.isClickable()){
            //Do nothing
            return value;
        }

        //If clickable

        //If the button needs to go up (released)
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //Set the proper background
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button_normal);
            //Restore the initial padding (0, 0, 0, 0)
            setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() - 10, getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom() + 10);
        }

        //If the button needs to go down (pressed)
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //Set the proper background
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button_pressed);
            //Set the proper padding to center the text (0, 10, 0, -10)
            setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() + 10, getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom() - 10);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Then using it wherever I need a button in this way:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.widgets.BlueOffsetButton
    style="@style/BlueButton"
    android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/settingsButton"
    android:text="@string/new_game_button_text"
    android:onClick="onClickNewGame" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the selector that has different drawables for each state (careful - your focus state is the same as your default state).

You could use a regular TextView, and set the background on that. Then when you have a click listener set on the TextView, it'll change background when you press it.

For the `state_focused` to be used, you'll have to make the `TextView` focusable.

Comment: I tried this one but the TextView doesn't slide down, it stays in the center of the clicked background, which is the same dimension of the normal one but gives the impression of 2D instead of 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Button` with a custom background drawable, similar to your selector. Buttons show centered text and are focusable by default.

If your background images are nine-patches, they may contain padding information. With the correct padding information, the text will be properly centered:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: I tried it but the text keeps staying in the center of the Button, and doesn't slide down. Could it be because both background (normal and pressed) have the same dimensions?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember that padding may not vary dynamically depending on the drawable state, so the text will not move automatically when the button is pressed. I'm afraid the only way to do what you want is to create a custom class extending Button which sets a View.OnTouchListener on itself to adjust the padding depending on the pressed state.